# Email address locked in field like box?

Tags: ajax, email, usability

So I dont know what it is called but I am looking for a way to box in the user entered email addresses like they do in hotmail, where any valid email is boxed into that rectangle locked email once it is validated in real time? Also in hotmail they allow you to remove it by clicking the X and edit it by clicking the edit icon. I want to add more features also appart from edit and delete, so I guess I use AJAX for this? I dont know the term for this so not sure how to search for sample code and design patters for this. Any idea on what this is called or sample links with different design patterns?

Answer (score 0):

You mean a [facebook-like autocompletion](http://www.rorcraft.com/2008/8/13/the-facebook-autocomplete-address-to-field/)? It uses AJAX (Javascript libraries: [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) / [Scriptacoulous](http://script.aculo.us/)).

Maybe this library is not perfectly suited to your use case, but you definitely need Javascript to do it as soon as the user enters it, but not necessarily AJAX - via javascript you can create input-hidden fields that will get submitted with the rest of the form.